# How to declare a variable once in a controller and it applies in all methods of the Controller

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am relatively new to the codeigniter framework and so far I am adapting well. I am curious if there is a short-cut to achieving my end result. Well, here is the problem at hand.

I am using this piece of code `$data['logged_in'] = $this->verify_min_level(1);` to verify if the user is logged in. What I am trying to avoid is using this code in every other method in the controller but instead declare it once and it applies globally to all methods in the controller.

I have tried using `protected $data['logged_in'] = $this->verify_min_level(1);` without any luck. Where am I going wrong and how do i correct it? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you should implement this using library.

Create library, that knows how to do user's authorization using sessions and/or cookies, database, knows to validate user's level.

Create file "Auth.php" in "system\application\libraries" directory.

```
class CI_Auth {

    var $obj;
    /**
     * Constructor
     *
     * @access  public
     */
    function CI_Auth()
    {
        /* here you get application's instance
        you can use it then as $this->obj->load->model('usermodel');
        $this->obj->usermodel->login($name, $pass);
        */
        $this->obj =& get_instance();
        /* init code using sessions, cookies, database */
    }

    function getUserId() {
        /* your code */
        return $user_id;
    }

    function getAuthLevel() {
        if ($this->getUserId()) {
            /* Your code */
            return $level;
        }

        return false;
    }
}
```

Then in system\application\config\autoload.php enable this library:

```
$autoload['libraries'] = array('database', 'session', 'auth');
```

And now you can use it in any controller, model or view as:

```
if (!$this->auth->getUserId())
{
     /* MUST LOG IN*/
}

if (!$this->auth->getAuthLevel() < 2)
{
     /* NO PERMISSIONS */
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Declare a variable in class and access it ...

```
class Class_name extends CI_Controller
{
    protected $logged_in;


    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->logged_in = $this->verify_min_level(1); // assign the value to variable
    }

    public function another_method()
    {
        echo $this->logged_in; // access the defined variable 
    }

}
```

Comment: This method is similar to what I have.

Answer (score 0):

Make a helper file in `helpers` directory. And define a function to check the user login. Like

```
if( ! function_exists('is_logged_in') ) {
    function is_logged_in() {
        $CI =& get_instance(); 

        // Now you can load any module here with $CI
        // Check user and return appropriate data
    }
}
```

Now autoload this helper so that you don't need to load it everytime, go to the `config/autoload.php` and navigate `$autoload['helper']` array, Now load this helper class here.

After doing this all, Your `is_logged_in()` function is available to `controller`, `model` and `view` you can apply anywhere.